# A specific msgbox is not showing

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to output several msgboxes at once which I did. Buy when I tried to output only one of them, nothing happens: I will show you only the ones which are not working. I want to show only these msgboxes if the cell value  is integer and is not between 6 and 72:

5.Font Size must be an integer from 6 till 72

6.Paragraph Spacing Before must be an integer from 6 till 72

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim cell2 As Range
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim cellVal As Integer
   Dim cellVal2 As Integer
   Dim sCellVal As String
   Dim a As Variant     
   Dim rngcheck As Range
   Dim rngcheck2 As Range
   sCellVal = Range("A2").Value
   cellVal = Range("B3").Value
   cellVal2 = Range("B4").Value

    If Not cellVal = (6 < 72) Then
         Cancel = True
         mess = mess & vbCrLf & "Font Size must be an integer from 6 till 72"
    End If

    If Not cellVal2 = (6 < 72) Then
         Cancel = True
         mess = mess & vbCrLf & "Paragraph Spacing Before must be an integer from 6 till 72"
    End If

    If mess <> "" Then MsgBox mess

End Sub
```

Comment: I *did* warn you about this in a comment on your previous question, but you blew me off ;-)

Comment: No , I just thought it would be ok, but then I realize it`s not the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line:

```
If Not cellVal = (6 < 72) Then
```

to

```
If cellVal < 6 Or cellVal > 72 Then
```

Do the same for `cellVal2`.

Comment: @user3701825 That's ok. You should have paid attention when I told you it didn't work previously ;-)

Comment: Of course my example means false because of the specific syntax

Comment: After close inspection, any problem can be seen :)

Comment: @user3701825 Yeah. I changed it to check if the value is outside the valid range instead of checking if it is not inside.

Comment: Yes that was the purpose in this case